# Passing function pointer to sketch function to be called from class member

Tags: c++, function-pointers

```
class foo{
  void bar(funct pointer) {
    pointer("xxx");
  }
}

In sketch:

void setup() {
   foo(myBar);
}

void myBar(char* arg) {
}
```

In my sketch, I call a member of a class (foo). I want that member to call a function in my code (myBar). What is the correct and simplest way to write this?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Mostly because your code is way too pseudoish. Please make it into a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is very hard to understand what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I find the question hard to understand, I think you my want to use a `std::function` object (C++11):

```
#include <functional>

void bar(const std::function<void(int)>& p_func);  // Takes a functor as an argument
```

The above takes a functor wrapping a function returning void with an `int` as a parameter. Usage:

```
void aFunction(int p_index);               // Typical function

std::function<void(int)> func = aFunction; // Make it a functor
bar(func);                                 // Pass it as an argument.
```

Inside `bar` you can use the functor passed as an argument using `()`. For example:

```
void bar(const std::function<void(int)>& p_func)
{
    p_func(5);  // Calls the function wrapped by p_func with 5 as an argument.
}
```

Functors are usable in a class as well. Note that a functor is not the same as a function pointer, but for your application, it seems more convenient. It also allows you to use lambda expressions (the C++ equivalent to anonymous functions)